# How to reposition the UINavigationBar in iOS?

Tags: ios

How to reposition the UINavigationBar in iOS? I need to have a sticky UI component on top of it so that it is persistent while the user going from the home page to the subpages?

Comment: The navigation bar is put there by the UINavigationController and its position doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a UINavigationViewController, the navigation created internally, and is positioned at the top. There isn't much you can do about it from within the view controller's in it's navigation stack.

However, navigation view controller, is just a view controller, and you can add it's view in another view, or embed it within a container view :

[image]

Now, you can have any custom content above (or around) your navigation controller

Further reading:

- [Creating a Custom Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller)
- [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)